# Content of an imported module in Julia

Tags: julia

Suppose I am using/importing a module in Julia:

```
using someModule
```

I didn't write the module and I would like to know what functions,variables,types, etc. are in the export line of that module. How van I do that?
(I'm using Julia 1.3.1)

Answer (score 4):

The [`names`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.names) function will list all names exported by the given module. For example:

```
julia> using Statistics

julia> names(Statistics)
14-element Array{Symbol,1}:
 :Statistics
 :cor
 :cov
 :mean
 :mean!
 :median
 :median!
 :middle
 :quantile
 :quantile!
 :std
 :stdm
 :var
 :varm
```